# 401 error code interpreted incorrectly in angular

Tags: angularjs, http-status-codes, intel-xdk

I am relatively new to angular so I am not sure if I am missing something here.

I have an Http Interceptor for adding JWT tokens to requests as well as handling responses from the server.

```
.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$window', function($q, $location, $window) {
   return {
       request: function(request) {
           console.log('myHttpInterceptor - request');
           return request;
       },
       requestError: function(requestError) {
           console.log('myHttpInterceptor - requestError');
           return requestError;
       },
       response: function(response) {
           console.log('myHttpInterceptor - response');
           return response;
       },
       responseError: function(responseError) {
           console.log('myHttpInterceptor - responseError');
           return responseError;
       }
   };
}]);


//Http Intercpetor to check auth failures 
angular.module("POSMobile").config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

So here is the problem, I am trying to handle a 401 Unauthorized error by changing the route to my login screen however the responseError listener doesn't ever seem to fire.

I have checked my iis logs and my service is definitely returning a 401 code

Here I did a test using Postman and picked up the 401[Screenshot of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOUwH.png)

However in my interceptor it evaluates like so [xdk debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Vvj.png)

and finally after the request is completed I get a 401 error in the debug console

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the data for the app on the device you are using to test

Comment: Thanks, It appeared to be cached data on my device.

Answer (score 0):

```
.factory('myHttpInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location) {
    return {
            responseError: function(response){
            console.log(response.status+' intercepted');
            return $q.reject(response);
           }
         };
     }]);
```

can you try this.

Comment: Hi Denny, I have tried this however it never actually hits the responseError function as the http status code is 200

Comment: I'm trying to handle 401 unauthorized

Comment: No, this is the problem I'm having. My web service returns a 401 status code, I know from checking the iis logs but my interceptor picks up a 200

Comment: Please check whether the response from the Api is in json format !